# Find the counts and occurrences of a column based on the name of another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  user             userid  user_id  ipaddr
1   'Client'         10      0        1.1.1.1
2   'admin1'         1       0        2.2.2.2
3   'Client'         3       0        1.1.1.1
4   'admin2'         5       0        3.3.3.3
5   'Client'         12      0        4.4.4.4
6   'admin1'         1       0        2.2.2.2
7   'Client'         21      0        4.4.4.4
8   'Client'         25      0        6.6.6.6
9   'Sub-Client 20'  35      0        4.4.4.4
```

I'm going to run a query which finds whic:

```
find in `ipaddr` column and find any ip-addresses are the same for other `user`s which names are `Client` or `Sub-Client`.
```

I hope I could've explained clear.

Suppose this:

```
ip-address 1.1.1.1 ==> Clients with userid 10, 3.
ip-address 4.4.4.4 ==> Clients with userid 12, 21, 35.
```

It shows these clients have logged in with the exact same IP.

I don't know what query to run, and I even don't know what's this called, so that I can google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A `GROUP BY`would eliminate the duplicates.
- the `GROUP_CONCAT` produces the string of userids
- THE `WHERE` reduces to the wanted user type
- And HAVING checks that only duplcate rows are in th result set

The result looks then like

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `user` VARCHAR(15),
  `userid` INTEGER,
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `ipaddr` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO tab
  (`id`, `user`, `userid`, `user_id`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Client', '10', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('2', 'admin1', '1', '0', '2.2.2.2'),
  ('3', 'Client', '3', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('4', 'admin2', '5', '0', '3.3.3.3'),
  ('5', 'Client', '12', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('6', 'admin1', '1', '0', '2.2.2.2'),
  ('7', 'Client', '21', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '4.4.4.4');
```

```
SELECT
  `ipaddr`, GROUP_CONCAT(`userid`  ORDER BY `userid` ASC  ) userid
FROM tab 
WHERE `user` = 'Client' OR `user` LIKE 'Sub-Client%'
GROUP BY `ipaddr`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER By `ipaddr`
```

| ipaddr | userid |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 3,10 |
| 4.4.4.4 | 12,21,35 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FRHDsXO4)

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Oops, I forgot to add some duplicate `userid` because one user may log in multiple times. https://dbfiddle.uk/AkANIkoH Do you please check it?

Comment: Grou_concar supports distinct see https://dbfiddle.uk/jyUW0AhA